# how to put the "<url>" to "</url>" into List?

Tags: scala, list

there is a List that read from a file, as follow:

```
lines: List[String] = List(a, b, <url>, <loc>1</loc>, </url>, c, <url>, <loc>2</loc>, </url>, d)
```

expected:

```
result = List(a, b, List(<url>, <loc>1</loc>, </url>), c, List(<url>, <loc>2</loc>, </url>), d)
```

Comment: You need to read about Scala's type system. Scala is *statically typed*, which means lists can't contain elements of different types. You need to rethink your approach and probably make a case class to represent your possibilities.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo is correct. What type is `result`? As presented it is not `List[String]`, neither is it `List[List[String]]`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo is it ok if expected: `result: List[List[String]] = List(List(a), List(b), List(<url>, <loc>1</loc>, </url>), List(c), List(<url>, <loc>2</loc>, </url>), List(d))`?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work.

```
val result = lines.foldRight(List[List[String]]()){
  case (s, lls) => if (s.matches("<.+>")
                    && lls.nonEmpty
                    && lls.head.head.matches("<.+>"))
                     (s :: lls.head) :: lls.tail
                   else
                     List(s) :: lls
  }
// result: List[List[String]] = List(List(a), List(b), List(<url>, <loc>1</loc>, </url>), List(c), List(<url>, <loc>2</loc>, </url>), List(d))
```

`lines` is folded from the right so that the result `List`, and sub-lists, can be built by pre-pending, which is the most efficient when working with lists.

Comment: thx. btw, if can judge by from "<url>" to "</url>". because some continuous lines contain "<xxx>"  but these are undesirable

Comment: `lines: List[String] = List(a, b, <url>, <loc>1</loc>, </url>, c, <url>, <loc>2</loc>, </url>, <id>d</id>, <lastmod>e</lastmod>)`

expected:

`result: List[List[String]] = List(List(a), List(b), List(<url>, <loc>1</loc>, </url>), List(c), List(<url>, <loc>2</loc>, </url>), List(<id>d</id>), List(<lastmod>e</lastmod>))`. only aggreate the elements from "<url>" to "</url>"

Comment: by your code. now i have an idea is to modify the regex .for example:`
val result = lines.foldRight(List[List[String]]()){
  case (s, lls) => if (s.matches(".*(</?url>|</?loc>).*")
    && lls.nonEmpty
    && lls.head.head.matches(".*(</?url>|</?loc>).*"))
    (s :: lls.head) :: lls.tail
  else
    List(s) :: lls
}
`